# Vue router: multiple router-views having to change only the content of one

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I have a left menu and two different content areas on the right:

```
<main-menu></main-menu>
<router-view name="area_1" />
<router-view name="area_2" />
```

The links in menu component are build from routes like this

```
<span v-for="route in this.$router.options.routes">
 <router-link :to="route.path" class="teal item">
  {{route.name}}
 </router-link>
</span>
```

The routes are like this

```
routes: [
          {
            path: '/c0',
            name: 'C0',
            components: { area_1: C0 }
          },
          {
            path: '/c1',
            name: 'C1',
            components: { area_1: C1 }
          },
          {
            path: '/c2',
            name: 'C2',
            components: { area_2: C2 }
```

I would like to click on C2 router-link and change only the content of area_2, but area_1 is emptyed while I would like to keep its current content (C0 **or** C1).

Ho can I achieve this?
Thanks in advance

Comment: What if the user accesses `/c2` directly from his browser, what component needs to be loaded. If you really want this behaviour, your application becomes unstable as a single url can have many different meanings, and thus becomes useless for debugging and linking purposes